# How are files converted to a Knowledge Base for the QnAMaker

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

I am new to the Microsoft Bot Framework and the Cognitive Services. For a project, I want to create a QnA Bot system which answers questions for a department. Those questions are coming from a PDF file.

The PDF file is like a manual. I tried to import the pdf to the qnamaker, but it doesn't convert the right sections. The goal is to create qna pairs from the pdf file and inject it to qna maker.

Me questions are:

- How can I create a bot which answers questions which are coming from the manual.pdf?
- How does QnAMaker convert qna pairs from a file? (Couldn't find this in the documentation)

I appreciate if you can take a look at the problem for any suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which SDK you are using, so here is some general info. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples) is the link to reference v4 bot samples in either C# or Node. Documentation can be read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) on how to design, build, and connect your bot.

Regarding importing a PDF into QnAMaker, please reference this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/concepts/data-sources-supported). It provides information on how to best setup your PDF source file to ensure the data is imported correctly.

Hope of help!